# What are the 3 dots in parameters?/What is a variable arity (...) parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters, arguments

I am wondering how the parameter of `...` works in Java. For example:

```
public void method1(boolean... arguments)
{
  //...     
}
```

Is this like an `array`? How I should access the parameter?

Comment: it is an array, and you can access it like an array with variable name `arguments`.

Comment: @jlordo i think precisely it is converted into array at run time . :)

Comment: It took much longer to type up this answer than to try for yourself...

Comment: I'm wonder why this question has so many upvotes. This is duplicate question and answer is easy to find. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010862/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-three-dots-in-a-method-declaration, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224252/what-are-these-three-dots-in-parameter-types etc. For me this question is similar to question like "what does the word 'private' mean".

Comment: @syb0rg Why did you retag this question 25 times (edits 13-37) over a span of 18 days, simply adding or removing the same tag each time?

Comment: @matts I was unsure whether or not the `method` tag was relevant or not.

Answer (score 3):

Its called [**Variable arguments**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) or in short **var-args**, introduced in Java 1.5.
The advantage is you can pass any number of arguments while calling the method.

For instance:

```
public void method1(boolean... arguments) throws Exception {
    for(boolean b: arguments){ // iterate over the var-args to get the arguments.
       System.out.println(b);
    }
 }
```

The above method can accept all the below method calls.

```
method1(true);
method1(true, false);
method1(true, false, false);
```

Comment: To improve your answer you could add info about how to get passed values :)

Comment: @Pshemo just added it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per other answer, it's a "varargs" parameter. Which is an array.

What many people don't realise is two important points:

- you may call the method with *no* parameters: `method1();`
- when you do, the parameter is an empty array

Many people assume it will be null if you specify no parameters, but null checking is unnecessary.

---

You can *force* a null to be passed by calling it like this:

```
method1((boolean[])null);
```

But I say if someone does this, let it explode.

Comment: I'm no Java user but that looks more like passing an array of booleans (that happens to have been converted from `null`) than forcing a null to be passed.