# Count variable parameters of lambda function in Java

Tags: java, lambda, variadic-functions

How can you count the number of parameters while initializing a variadic function/lambda expression?
Or: how can you determine the arity of a lambda-expression?

Example:

```
public class MathFunction{

  private java.util.function.Function <double[], Double> function = null;
  private int length = 0;

  public MathFunction ( Function <double[], Double> pFunction ){    
    this.function = pFunction;
    this.length = ???
  }
}
```

Now, if you init a new `MathFunction` like this,

```
MathFunction func = new MathFunction((x) -> Math.pow(x[0], x[1]));
```

how can you count the passed parameters (here: two) in the `MathFunction`-constructor ?

Comment: You could try longer and longer arrays until an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is not caught. This would be insane though. The sane way is just to pass the length as a separate argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

`MathFunction` declares a constructor that takes a single parameter, which is a `Function`. This function will operate on a double array and return a `Double`. But note that this function can operate on *any* double arrays, of any length.

There is no way the function can know the length of the array: it only knows that it can operate on a double array, whatever its length.

Consider these lambdas:

```
x -> Math.pow(x[0], x[1])
x -> Math.pow(x[0], x[1]) + x[2]
x -> x[0]
```

They all valid lambdas, all of them complies to the same `Function<double[], Double>` and all of them (would) operate on an array of different lengths.

Your only solution would be to pass the length of the array to the constructor as a second argument.

```
public MathFunction ( Function <double[], Double> pFunction, int length ){    
    this.function = pFunction;
    this.length = length;
}
```

By the way, this is not called arity, this term refer to [variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14739831/1743880).