# How to create an URI from a PHP stack trace to Eclipse IDE

Tags: php, eclipse

While debugging a PHP application an error message appears in the browser with a complete stack trace. Is it possible to create hyperlinks from the files + line numbers that automatically navigates to Eclipse?

The closest answer that I've found is this one:
[Create an URI for an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526011/create-an-uri-for-an-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is no for now.

Eclipse team works on ability to implement URL handlers like (eclipse://path_to_something), see for example [bug 530835](http://eclip.se/530835)

Comment: Great answer. The bug report is from the same date as my question. It's really fantasic how fast the Eclipse team picks this up.